# Ingress handling switching between two services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i have a service running on kubernetes and exposed using ingress
my question is : can ingress handle the switching between this service and another service from outside the kubernetes? if something happens on the service on k8s it switches to the outside service (like n 404 error)
thanks in advance

Comment: No, i think does not have this switching feature in between k8s cluster service and outside of k8s cluster service. Its not actually needed when you have k8s cluster.

Comment: the point is about failover strategy to do that using ingress so if a user go through a path on the service on kubernetes and gets 404 error for example , the ingress will redirect the client to the service outside the kubernetes

Comment: Hi, I don't think this will be possible with an `Ingress` resource. Could you please elaborate more on the use case? I'd reckon this shouldn't happen as in general there would be multiple `Pods` in the `Deployment` that would handle the request. Are you intending to have the situation where all the `Pods` are not in `Ready` state? Your `liveness` Probes should be able to distinguish a correctly running `Pod` that the request will be sent to.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a default backend: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/

There are a couple of things you can configure to handle additional errors as well, see:

- https://medium.com/alterway/how-to-custom-your-default-backend-on-kubernetes-nginx-controller-9b38048e10c0
- https://itnext.io/custom-error-page-for-nginx-ingress-controller-cca4cfa82bb9

Comment: my question if the service looks like it's running well but failed in some path .. www.example.com looks well .. www.example.com/path gives error 404 .. i need depending on that error the ingress sends all requests on www.example.com to the outside service